# Examples of one-dimensional non-Cohen Macaulay rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Can you offer some examples of such rings, other than $\frac{k[x,y]}{(x^{2}, xy)}$.  Thanks.

Comment: You can find some examples in part 1) of this: (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7556/some-examples-of-depth/7564#7564)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In dimension $1$, Cohen-Macaulay just mean *unmixed*, so all the associated primes have the same dimension. Thus the easiest way to cook up a non-CM ring of dimension $1$ is: Pick your favorite regular ring (say $A=k[x,y,z]$). Take an ideal of dimension $1$, say $I=(x,y)$. Take another ideal of dimension $0$, say $J=(x^3,y^4,z^5)$ such that $J$ is not contained in $I$. Now take $R=A/(I\cap J)$. Geometrically we just throw 2 things of pure dimensions $1$ and $0$ together. In some sense, all non-CM rings of dimension $1$ arise this way.

Comment: Taking $R=A/(IJ)$ also works. 

Answer (score 6):

You aren't going to find noetherian graded algebras $A$ much different from this.  If $A$ is such an algebra with irrelevant ideal $A_+$ then there is a nonzero homogeneous element $x$ of positive degree such that $xA_+=0$. Similarly for local rings $R$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, such that $R$ has dimension one and in not Cohen-Macaulay, there is a nonzero $x\in\mathfrak{m}$ such that $x\mathfrak{m}=0$. See K. Baclawski and A. M. Garsia, *Advances in Math.* **39** (1981), 155--184 (Lemma 2.2) and I. Kaplansky, *Commutative Rings*, revised ed. (Theorem 82).